# How to investigate and fix libpjsua2.so crash

Tags: c++, android-ndk, pjsip

```
SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR at 0x00000008

0  libpjsua2.so                   0x56585a88 pj::Call::getInfo() const
1  libpjsua2.so                   0x56546b44 std::allocator<pj::CallMediaInfo>::allocator()
```

I'm using pjsip for one of my hobby project(complies with GPL). Above you can see the stacktrace received from crashlytics. I'm using Java wrapper for pjsip.

There are a lot of users(50 %) affected by this error, however I'm not able to reproduce it on my local devices.

Not sure but I suspect that following java call lead to error. Which call C++ via JNI

```
public void notifyCallState(MyCall call) {
    if (currentCall == null || call.getId() != currentCall.getId())
        return;

    CallInfo ci;
    try {
        ci = call.getInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ci = null;
    }
    Message m = Message.obtain(handler, MSG_TYPE.CALL_STATE, ci);
    m.sendToTarget();

    if (ci != null && ci.getState() == pjsip_inv_state.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        currentCall = null;
    }
}
```

Code snippet is taken from examples which come from psjua download. [Link to http repo](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/src/org/pjsip/pjsua2/app/). My code is the same. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: Please correct the tag from c to c++ or whatever language this is. It's not C.

Comment: Your SIGSEGV trace is C++. C doesn't have std::allocator.

Comment: Fixed. Indeed pjsua2 is written on C++

Comment: What is allocator btw ? Is it something like constructor ? What means 1 trace output, creation of CallMediaInfo ?

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace is looks like `call` is null, and `getId` method is at 0x8 offset.

If that's really the case, the fix is to make sure `notifyCallState` isn't called with `null` argument, or to check it inside the method, i.e.:

```
if (call == null || currentCall == null || call.getId() != currentCall.getId())
    return;
```

Comment: If `call` is null, then the problem is outside the code posted.

Comment: if call is null, then NPE will be thrown from Java code, when calling getId method. But this is C crash, occurs when invoking JNI method

Answer (score 0):

Your program is most likely hitting some sort of memory corruption and most likely heap memory. Following observations points towards that.

1. I'm not able to reproduce it on my local devices. This is common symptoms of memory corruption.
2. stack-trace includes std::allocator which indicates that program has been terminated while using(creating/deleting/accessing) the heap memory.

**Recommendation**

1. We should try to review the code logic and whether this program uses **Interop** service in correct way.I do not have much idea regarding this however it looks like your program logic does have JAVA/C++ interaction. If we are lucky we might get something obvious here and we are done.
2. If the stack-trace are after effect of something else, then we are in trouble we might have to take approach suggested in below posts.

**Windows Platform**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074401/2724703

**Linux Platform**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22658693/2724703

**Android Platform**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663360/2724703

You may want to refer the above posts to get the idea about how to approach on such problems. As per my understanding, android platform does not have dynamic tools so you might have to use some versions(debug/additional logging) of your library.

I do hope that, above information might be useful and would have given some guidelines to approach your problem.